# Firebase for iOS inside framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

I have a project who needs `firebase` for login and ...

So I decided to create a project(*Cocoa Touch Framework*) inside my *workspace* to handle all firebase operation.

The firebase framework added to main app via **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

I also using `cocoa pods`

My pod file is something like this:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def firebase
    # Firebase
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
end

target 'RKFirebaseModule' do
    use_frameworks!
    workspace 'Main'
    project 'RKFirebaseModule/RKFirebaseModule.xcodeproj'

    firebase
end

target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace 'Main'
  project 'App.xcodeproj'

  rx_swift
  rx_cocoa

end
```

at this point if I run the app I will get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /.../RKFirebaseModule
  Reason: image not found
```

So I tried to solve this problem by adding firebase dependencies to the main app (in pod file):

```
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace 'Main'
  project 'App.xcodeproj'

  rx_swift
  rx_cocoa
  firebase

end
```

Now I'm getting bunch of error relating to duplicate implementation of classes like this:

```
Class FIRAIdentifiers is implemented in both /.../RKFirebaseModule.framework/RKFirebaseModule and /.../App.app/App. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

So how can I solve this problems?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. tnx

**EDIT 1:** Similar cases founds here, but non of the mentioned methods works for me.

1.[Duplicate symbols when framework target has a static dependency](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7126)

2.[Duplicate classes warnings at runtime when multiple targets are contained in the same project](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7155)

**EDIT 2:** The first problem is normal and it is due to this fact that *cocoa pods* won't bundle the dependencies into the framework, so I have to use same dependencies for main app.

The second problem caused by some of the firebase static framework, so my framework have a copy of *firebase static frameworks* and main app has a copy too, so the error is expected here.

I have to remove duplicate *static frameworks*. HOW?

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to make it work @mehdok?

Comment: @JoanCardona, no, I moved all firebase operation to the main project instead of framework.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I was using a framework I built and this framework was used in projects that used firebase as well. The workaround I came across was through using cocoapods. I built my framework as a static framework using cocoapods (check .podspec below):

```
  s.static_framework = true
  s.dependency 'Firebase'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
```

The example app i was working on imported my framework via cocoapods as well

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'gameballSDK', :path => "~/Documents/Libraries/gameballSDK"
```

Comment: are you using the same approach now?